# What are all open source applications using Berkeley DB?

Tags: java, open-source, berkeley-db, berkeley-db-je

I am learning Berkeley DB and its usages. Could somebody point the open source applications using BerkeleyDB.

Though I am using Java (BDB Java edition), I am open to refer other programming languages too.

Comment: Obviously, nobody can give you a list of **all** open source applications that use BDB.  You'll have to settle for **some**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of open source applications that use Berkeley DB, Berkeley DB Java Edition and Berkeley DB XML. Remember, BDB and BDB JE are different products. BDB and BDB JE share the same Java API for the most part, but the storage mechanisms are different. BDB also has C, C++, C#, SQL, Perl, Python, PHP, Ruby and other APIs.

The Wikipedia article has a good list. I've listed a few more. It's hard to know which open source projects use BDB since that's part of the nature of open source. You download it and you use it. Period.

A short list of projects that use Berkeley DB include: Sendmail, Postfix, OpenLDAP, Redhat LDAP Directory, Apache Directory Services, Kerberos Network Authentication, OpenOffice, XEmacs, Hypergraphdb, JasperReports,

A short list of projects that use Berkeley DB Java Edition include: Voldemort, The Internet Archive Wayback machine, Hajo (http://sourceforge.net/projects/berkeleydbtools/).

A short list of projects that use Berkeley DB XML include: XQilla, MapGuide (http://mapguide.osgeo.org/), Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

The first that comes to mind is that Subversion has an optional BDB backend. The newer FSFS backend is more popular these days, but BerkeleyDB is still an option.

[Wikipedia also has a long list of applications that use it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB#Programs_that_use_Berkeley_DB). I'm not sure how many of those are Open Source, though...